# Is there a way to include all columns in a groupby for similar data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have been doing a groupby on sales data which looks like the below dataframe to calculate the sum of quantities and cost.

| Product | Quantity | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | 50 |
| A | 12 | 50 |
| A | 12 | 50 |
| A | 12 | 70 |
| A | 12 | 50 |

The groupby
`df.loc[:, ['Product', 'Quantity', 'Cost']].groupby(['Product']).sum())`
though results in

|  | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Product |  |
| A | 270 |

Is there a way to also include the sum of quantities for the scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.agg()` where you specify how do you want to aggregate different columns:

```
print(df.groupby("Product").agg({"Quantity": "sum", "Cost": "sum"}))
```

Prints:

```
         Quantity  Cost
Product                
A              60   270
```